# Using Gparted and installing Windows 10 after Linux

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot, gparted, window

I recently built a computer and put LinuxMint 17.3 on it right away. I now have a free copy of Windows 10. I haven't really been able to find detailed instructions on how to install Windows while keeping Linux. I know I have to re-size partitions but I have never really used these tools before and would rather not just mess around with them until I figure it out.

Comment: The original answerer is right, but if you want a more detailed (but still applicable to all Linux distros) answer with each step explained, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu There's also a great Ubuntu-specific answer in there which is different and may be better for some people.

Answer (score 21):

First if you aren't sure of what you are doing, make a backup of your important data. Then you have to follow 3 steps :

1. Open `GParted` and resize your linux partition(s) in order to have at least 20Gb of free space.
2. Boot on the `Windows installation DVD/USB` and select "Unallocated space" to not override your linux partition(s).
3. Finally you have to boot on a `Linux live DVD/USB` to re-install Grub (*the boot loader*) as [explained here](https://askubuntu.com/a/83796).

I assure you that if you pay attention there will be no problem for your linux. Good luck !

P.S. : If you want me to give more informations about step 3, I can explain you the steps (`mount/dev/xxx /mnt`, `chroot /mnt`, `update-grub`, `grub-install`, `umount`, ...).